# Android: Use DialogFragment as Container for custom Dialog Yes or No?

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-activity, android-dialogfragment

Ok guys, this is my first question on SO and I would like know, if it is really necessary to use DialogFragment as a Container for my simple custom Dialog that I have in my Activity.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    // VARS:
    private Button buttonShowDialog;
    private Dialog dialogSimple;
    private Button buttonOK;
    private Button buttonCancel;

    // ONCREATE:
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_main);
        buttonShowDialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_showdialog);
        buttonShowDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener)
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {
                if (dialogSimple != null)
                {
                    dialogSimple.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    showDialog();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // SHOW DIALOG:
    private void showDialog()
    {
        dialogSimple = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialogSimple.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        buttonOK = (Button) dialogSimple.findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
        buttonCanel = (Button) dialogSimple.findViewById(R.id.button_cancel);

        buttonOK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener)
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {
                doSomeStuff();
            }
        });

        buttonCanel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener)
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {
                dialogSimple.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialogSimple.show();
    }
}
```

My manifest entry for the activity:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize"
```

I tested and it worked fine with:
    API 8 (Device), 
        9 (Device), 
        10 (Emu), 
        11 (Emu), 
        16 (Emu), 
        17 (Device), 
        18 (Device) 
    and 19 (Emu)

So my worries are, that with this procedure my App could misbehave on some devices, because the Dialog is not in a DialogFragment.

**My Questions**:

1. Are my worries correct?
2. If yes, I would like to know what kind of bad things could happen in my App by using this procedure?
3. Maybe some sample code of doing it right in a clean and also short way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not required. Just [recommended](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

But you can achieve it with an alert dialog:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder bld = new AlertDialog.Builder();
 bld.setMessage(...);
 bld.setPositiveButton(...);
 bld.setNegativeButton(...);
 bld.create().show();
```

Comment: Wow Nick, your answer was hella fast! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The Dialog class is a base class for showing dialogs. You should use a more specific subclass for displaying a Yes/No dialog. For example: AlertDialog.

```
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles)
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // User cancelled the dialog
               }
           });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and show it
    builder.create().show();
```

You can find more details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

Comment: It took longer for me to reply because I wanted to provide a PROPER answer.

Comment: Thank you too NPE for your answer. 
That's what I also read 1 day ago on the Android Developers site, that you should avoid instantiating Dialog directly. But there are no explanations why and what could happen if yes. Only the advantages (except more code :)). Maybe you have an answer or link to the disadvantages? I'm just curious.